# upgrade GCC C++ devtoolset 2 on Redhat 6.8

Tags: gcc, redhat, xgboost

we are using RedHat 6.8 with the GCC C++ to v4.8 in order to compile the python package xgboost

Try yum install --nogpgcheck devtoolset-2 and getting the follow errors

--> Processing Dependency: xml-commons-jaxp-1.3-apis for package: devtoolset-2-objectweb-asm-3.3.1-6.el6.noarch
        ---> Package devtoolset-2-systemtap-runtime.x86_64 0:2.1-8.el6 will be installed
        --> Finished Dependency Resolution
        Error: Package: devtoolset-2-ant-apache-xalan2-1.8.4-12.el6.noarch (slc6-devtoolset)
           Requires: regexp
        Error: Package: devtoolset-2-axis-1.4-23.el6.noarch (slc6-devtoolset)
           Requires: jakarta-commons-httpclient >= 1:3.0
        Error: Package: devtoolset-2-junit-4.11-6.el6.1.noarch (slc6-devtoolset)
           Requires: hamcrest
        Error: Package: 1:devtoolset-2-eclipse-platform-4.3.1-8.el6.x86_64 (slc6-devtoolset)
           Requires: xml-commons-apis
        Error: Package: devtoolset-2-eclipse-emf-xsd-sdk-2.9.1-2.el6.noarch (slc6-devtoolset)

Anyone know how to get around it?

Thanks,

Comment: Recommend against devtoolset packages as they are kind of bad. Go with a PaaS solution for the application and then it will be easy.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to take the subscription from the RedHat web site(It is free),

and after registering follow below commands

for subscription follow this link [Redahat subscription](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/253273)

```
#subscription-manager register --username your suscribed username --password your password  
#subscription-manager list --avilable
#subscription-manager subscribe --pool= Enter your pool serial
#subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-server-rhscl-6-rpms
#subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-6-server-optional-rpms
#yum install devtoolset-6-toolchain [ for install directly]
#scl enable devtoolset-6 bash
```

For making it as permanent:

Add this to .bashrc (for root and your user)

```
#source scl_source enable devtoolset-6
```